# Center footer in prestashop

Tags: css, footer, prestashop

I'm modifying a theme for my client and I ran into a small problem.

I can't center the footer.

The question is, how can I add a div to the footer as a container witch I would center using CSS? Should I create a new hook or is there a workaround?

Thanks,

here is the url: [Link to the store](http://growmundocannabico.com/es/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily. There is no need to create a new hook for it. If you need a module, you can create one module if the content of the that section are dynamic. But the simple way is

1) Open footer file which is **themes/your_ps_theme_name_folder/footer.tpl**

2) There you will find footer section along with the footer hook. Place your div container as told by Miljan Puzović and the css to global.css file placed in the css folder of your theme.

That is the simplest way. Hope this will help

Comment: Hi, thanks.

One question, I'm Joomla fan, and does Prestashop has something similar to Joomla's custom HTML module?

Thanks,

Comment: You are welcome. May be there will be any, i dont know about it. But prestashop is not like joomla and not complex like joomla also. Its html is very simple and you can easily understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap content of footer inside another container with fixed width and set margin to `0 auto`. Something like this:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="some_container">
          <!-- current content in footer -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And then set in CSS

```
#some_container {width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: yes, but it's prestashop theme, it's in php and the content displayed inside the hook. 

how can I add a div into a hook?

Comment: This is just basic solution of your problem, goal to be reached. I can't help you with every detail. Try to open those PHP files and figure out where to change/add html elements, od edit PHP code to get structure from above.